# SQLAlchemy, how does it connect to an existing MYSQL database created in mysql workbench?

Tags: mysql, sql, python-2.7, sqlalchemy, mysql-workbench

I am trying to create simple GUI python applications for populating an existing MYSQL database. Should I use sqlalchemy to connect to the server?  I'm just wondering how Alchemy can connect to the existing DB which was created using MYSQL workbench?
Usually I create the database and tables using sqlalchemy that's why I can query and edit it.  But for this case,  the DB is already created.  I guess the question would be how do I create the SQLAlchemy code of the existing DB? 
Sorry for the lack of better words to explain my problem. I'm not that familiar with Database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sqlacodegen](https://bitbucket.org/agronholm/sqlacodegen) to generate python code for models in an existing database.  You can also use SQLAlchemy's built in ability to [reflect the tables](http://sqlalchemy.readthedocs.org/en/rel_0_9/core/reflection.html) or even [map them to classes](http://sqlalchemy.readthedocs.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/automap.html) to dynamically load everything at runtime.  SQLAlchemy doesn't care where the database came from, just where it is and what it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to existing table in your database using SQLAlchemy it is easy even if the tables are not created using SQLAlchemy.
For this you need to use flask framework and flask-sqlalchemy

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "any key"
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = 'mysql://root@localhost/database_name'
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
db.init_app(app)
```

Classes need to be created to map these to your tables in the database .
Say for example database has a table named STUDENT for this table the class will be something like this

```
class Student(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "STUDENT"
    id= db.Column(db.Integer , primary_key = True , nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.Integer)
    address= db.Column(db.String)
    grade= db.Column(db.String)
    year = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

To get the SQLAlchemy data types : https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/types.html
Similarly other classes can be created for other tables as well.
And to perform any operation on the data the class object type has to be used.
Say you wanted to get the student list

```
stu_obj = Student.query.all()
```

This will give you the list of all the rows in the student table.
For SQLAlchemy ORM queries 
 : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy_orm_declaring_mapping.htm